# Elasticsearch advanced search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

I find Elasticsearch gem and want to use it. For example I have:

Method in `app/controller/search_controller.rb`:

```
def search
  if params[:q].nil?
    @articles = []
  else
    @articles = Article.search params[:q]
  end
end
```

View at `app/views/search/search.html.erb`:

```
<h1>Articles Search</h1>

<%= form_for search_path, method: :get do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label "Search for" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Go", name: nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<ul>
  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <li>
      <h3>
        <%= link_to article.title, controller: "articles", action: "show", id: article._id%>
      </h3>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

And search route at `config/routes.rb`:

```
get 'search', to: 'search#search'
```

I want to create advansed search. 
For example, when I write `#cucumber` in search line, I want to get the following line: `localhost:3000/tagged?tag=cucumber`. 
It is necessary for me to display products by tag. How to do it?

Comment: If you want to interpret input `#cucumber` as 'search by tag cucumber', you will have to to so manually. It has nothing to do with elasticsearch. Besides that you will have to create an elasticsearch index for articles, set up model Article callbacks to update the index and build queries for your search scenarios. See also docs for [elasticsearch-rails](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails) and [elasticsearch-model](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will prefer to do this in your action.

```
tags = params[:q].present? ? params[:q].scan(/#[^ #]+/).collect{|tag| tag.gsub(/#/, '')} : []
```

now you can use this array of tags in search function